# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-widget

I know this question had been asked many times but I still cant figure it out yet.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from . models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

ACCOUNT_TYPE = [
    ('SPO', 'SPO'),
    ('Call Agent', 'Call Agent'),
    ('Accountant', 'Accountant'),
]

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    name            = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    account_type    = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ACCOUNT_TYPE)

    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required':'required'}),
            'account_type': forms.ChoiceField(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required':'required'})
        }
```

What am I doing wrong. I have made every possible changes but nothing had changed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`forms.CharField(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) is a ***Django Form Field***, which is not a [***widget***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#module-django.forms.widgets). Use [**`forms.TextInput(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput) instead

```
widgets = {
    'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'required'}),
    'account_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'required'})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error goes away but its not making any difference, the class: form-control nor the placeholder if I place them on widgets is not rendering in the template. What is wrong here.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know about that. Anyway, please ask a new question regarding your new issue.

Comment: Thank you. I got the issue. Me being so fool passing the widgets on the class meta instead I've to pass that into createuserform class

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly use **the form field [forms.CharField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#charfield)** for **"widgets"**:

```py
widgets = {
    'name': forms.CharField(attrs={...}),
    'account_type': forms.ChoiceField(attrs={...})
}
```

Instead, you need to use **the widget [forms.TextInput()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#textinput)** for **"widgets"**:

```py
widgets = {
    'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={...}),
    'account_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={...})
}
```